# How to define custom compiler for some file type in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: compiler-construction, intellij-idea, customization, protocol-buffers

Is it possible to define custom compiler for particular file type in IntelliJ IDEA ? I found how to define custom formatting though.

I have bunch of `*.proto` files in my project. It would be nice if I have define external executable that compiles them into `.java` files that `javac` will further compile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doesn't the protobuf plugin (http://plugins.intellij.net/plugin/?idea&id=4942) do this for you?

If not, you should create a plugin and implement TranslatingCompiler there. See, for example, Groovy plugin source for the code samples.

Comment: I'd suggest you to contact the author and possibly contribute to this plugin to enhance it

Comment: Yeah, I filed github issue. We'll what he says.